# Is it a way to get Azure Open AI deployment plan rate limits programmatically?

Tags: langchain, py-langchain, azure-openai

I would like to get the rate limits (requests/tokens per minute) for Azure Open AI deployment plan programmatically. But cannot find the way to do this from the source code.

I use langchain python module, instantiate a AzureChatOpenAI instance and work with the chains.

Is there a way to get the limits using the AzureChatOpenAI?

Answer (score 0):

You can check with custom CallBackHandler

```
    from langchain.callbacks.base import BaseCallbackHandler
    from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
    from langchain.schema import HumanMessage


    class MyCustomHandler(BaseCallbackHandler):
        def on_llm_new_token(self, token: str, **kwargs) -> None:
            print(f"My custom handler, token: {token}")


    # To enable streaming, we pass in `streaming=True` to the ChatModel constructor
    # Additionally, we pass in a list with our custom handler
    chat = ChatOpenAI(max_tokens=25, streaming=True, callbacks=[MyCustomHandler()])

    chat([HumanMessage(content="Tell me a joke")])
```

Comment: thank for your answer, but how that way I get the tokens limit per minute?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/quotas-limits

Comment: yes, this is a regional quota limits, but my Azure Open API Deployment plan can differ from these values.

Comment: you can check your account for the max allowed tokens value, based on this value you can code to check token counts before making requests. this can be easily done with CallBackManager once you know the value. You can also check with support team if you are not able to find the values for your account

Comment: I know that I can check the max allowed tokens in my account. 
The question was not about it, I was interested in how to get these values from the source code. I do not see such option.

Comment: Oh, these values may be available in response header. OpenAI provide these values in response header. You can check same way for Azure OpenAI